Setting Up Spotipy PKCE Authorization within a Flask App
I've created a program utilizing Spotipy's library to connect to the Spotify API using the OAuth2 Authorization. I decided to put this program on some sort of server (using Flask and pythonanywhere) so that myself, and anyone interested can use the program whenever. However, I realized it is best practice to use PKCE when doing user to server endpoints. I would like to use Spotipy's library but I am not too sure how to use it's PKCE authorization with Flask. When the program was ran locally, I used OAuth2 and it worked fine.... Even when I used OAuth2 in a Flask app, it worked.
I've searched endlessly for something about Spotipy's PKCE auth flow but nothing, so I thought I'd make this thread.

I've searched endlessly for something about Spotipy's PKCE auth flow but nothing, so I thought I'd make this thread.
Should I just drop the Spotipy library and connect to Spotify's API using the 'bare-bones' url way?
TLDR: I don't know how to use Spotipy's PKCE authflow using flask. I keep getting:
spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: error: invalid_grant, error_description: code_verifier was incorrect

'token_info = auth_manager.get_access_token(code)['access_token']' in @api_callback()

#Import Libraries
import spotipy
import time
import os
import sys
from spotipy import oauth2
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, request, session, redirect, render_template
from flask_session import Session
from credentials import CLIENT_ID,SCOPE,REDIRECTURI

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(15).hex()
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['SESSION_FILE_DIR'] = '/pythonanywhere/mysite'
Session(app)

##################################################################
### FLASK PAGES ###

#index
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html") #home page with link to '/login'

### authorizations ###

@app.route("/login")
def verify():
    cache_handler = spotipy.cache_handler.FlaskSessionCacheHandler(session)
    auth_manager = oauth2.SpotifyPKCE(CLIENT_ID,REDIRECTURI,scope=SCOPE,cache_handler=cache_handler)
    auth_url = auth_manager.get_authorize_url()

    return redirect(auth_url)

@app.route('/callback')
def api_callback():
    cache_handler = spotipy.cache_handler.FlaskSessionCacheHandler(session)
    auth_manager = oauth2.SpotifyPKCE(CLIENT_ID,REDIRECTURI,scope=SCOPE,cache_handler=cache_handler)
    
    code = request.args.get('code')

    token_info = auth_manager.get_access_token(code)['access_token']
    session['token_info'] = token_info

    return redirect('/playlist')

#display page
@app.route('/playlist')
def playlist():    
    cache_handler = spotipy.cache_handler.FlaskSessionCacheHandler(session)
    auth_manager = oauth2.SpotifyPKCE(CLIENT_ID,REDIRECTURI,scope=SCOPE,cache_handler=cache_handler)
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(oauth_manager=auth_manager)

    user = sp.current_user()
    username = user['display_name']
    userid = user['id']
    
    #call methods
    
    return render_template('display.html')

##################################################################
### METHODS ###

    # rest of script #

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)


